# ISBLANK() or LEN() not working while checking Calculated Column which returns Date by formula for SharePoint List

Tags: list, sharepoint, formula, calculated-columns, sharepoint-designer

Three *choice* fields **`1st route`, `2nd route`, `3rd route`** all containing text. And **1st route**, **2nd route**, **3rd route** columns have values like:
[image: Dropdown values]

Now I have three more columns:

1) **`Current Route`** (Calculated column checks above given *choice columns* and returns *Single line text*)

```
=IF(ISBLANK([3rd route]),IF(ISBLANK([2nd route]),IF(ISBLANK([1st route]),"",[1st route]),[2nd route]),[3rd route])
```

[image: See formula for Current Route]

2) **`Current Route Date`** (Calculated column checks `Current Route` and returns *Date*)

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK([3rd route]),ISBLANK([3rd route date])),IF(OR(ISBLANK([2nd route]),ISBLANK([2nd route date])),IF(OR(ISBLANK([1st route]),ISBLANK([1st route date])),"",[1st route date]),[2nd route date]),[3rd route date])
```

[image: See formula for Current Route Date]

3) Problematic column -> **`Days Elapsed`** (Calculated column checks `=IF(ISBLANK([Current Route Date]),0,TODAY()-[Current Route Date])` and returns *Number*)

or I have also tried

```
 =IF(OR(LEN([Current Route Date])=0,TODAY()-[Current Route Date]<0),0,TODAY()-[Current Route Date])
```

[image: See formula for Days Elapsed]

It always returns **#Value!** or **#Name?** when **`Current Route Date`** is empty which if you see the formula it returns **""** and which if I am not wrong stores "**01/01/1900**" in **Current Route Date** column. So why doesn't *ISBLANK()* succeeds in checking Current Route Date?
[image: See List View]

Answer (score 2):

Per my test, I could reproduce the issue on my end. As a workaround, we could use this formula instead:

```
=IF([Current Route Date]="",TODAY()-[Current Route Date])
```

Comment: It is not working for me. I have also tried with `=IF(OR(LEN([Current Route Date])=0,TODAY()-[Current Route Date]<0),0,TODAY()-[Current Route Date])`

Comment: I have added in the formulas in question... edited my post. Please see!

Answer (score 1):

Michael Han has the right answer. As to why your examples did not work:

The OR is testing both conditions, and the second fails as "" is not a date.

So instead of:

```
=IF(OR(LEN([Current Route Date])=0,TODAY()-[Current Route Date]<0),0,TODAY()-[Current Route Date])
```

Try:

```
=IF(LEN([Current Route Date])=0,
   0,
   IF(TODAY()-[Current Route Date]<0,
      0,
      TODAY()-[Current Route Date]))
```

As to the ISBLANK, "" is not blank, it is a value.

Try changing:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Current Route Date]),0,TODAY()-[Current Route Date])
```

to

```
=IF([Current Route Date]="",0,TODAY()-[Current Route Date])
```

Answer (score 1):

Validation formula to enforce either null or today’s date in a date field

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(DATE_VAL)=TRUE,DATE_VAL=TODAY()),TRUE,FALSE)
```

tested and works fine

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. Please remember to always format your code properly.